# How to pick password from property/variable/config for SU command

Tags: unix

I want to switch user from other user. when i enter command to switch it is asking for the password. I want to avoid entering password manually, instead password should be pick from properties/config/variable ect.
I want to create Shell script which will switch user.

```
> su - user1 (click enter)
Password: (i want to avoid entering password manually)
```

Comment: What about `sudo`?

Comment: i don't have access to `sudo`

Comment: Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping with programming code problems. Sorry, but your Q is off-topic. Please delete here and repost to https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.